# Json object values manipulation in Spring-boot

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, gson

I have a sample json as follows

```
[{"state":"Completed","mignum":146289,"projectleader":"Eric Lok","productiondate":"Jun 6, 2018","installationtiers":"Windows Server","targetplatform":"Production","apprelated":"UPS Pickup Point Web Application","appversion":"2.25"},
{"state":"Completed","mignum":146381,"projectleader":"James Rice","productiondate":"Jun 6, 2018","installationtiers":"Linux Web WL10","targetplatform":"Production","apprelated":"Content Only","appversion":""},
{"state":"Pending Migration to Production","mignum":146461,"projectleader":"Nishith Jani","productiondate":"Jun 6, 2018","installationtiers":"Linux BEA WL12","targetplatform":"Production","apprelated":"Tracking Comp","appversion":"1801.20"},
{"state":"Completed","mignum":146574,"projectleader":"Nishith Jani","productiondate":"Jun 6, 2018","installationtiers":"Linux BEA WL12","targetplatform":"Production","apprelated":"Tracking Comp","appversion":"01-00-07-17"}
{"state":Pending Approval by Development in Windward","mignum":146289,"projectleader":"Eric Lok","productiondate":"Jun 6, 2018","installationtiers":"Windows Server","targetplatform":"Production","apprelated":"UPS Pickup Point Web Application","appversion":"2.25"},
{"state":"Completed","mignum":146381,"projectleader":"James Rice","productiondate":"Jun 6, 2018","installationtiers":"Linux Web WL10","targetplatform":"Production","apprelated":"Content Only","appversion":""},
{"state":"Pending Approval by Development in Windward","mignum":146461,"projectleader":"Nishith Jani","productiondate":"Jun 6, 2018","installationtiers":"Linux BEA WL12","targetplatform":"Production","apprelated":"Tracking Comp","appversion":"1801.20"},
{"state":"Pending Migration to Production","mignum":146574,"projectleader":"Nishith Jani","productiondate":"Jun 6, 2018","installationtiers":"Linux BEA WL12","targetplatform":"Production","apprelated":"Tracking Comp","appversion":"01-00-07-17"}
]
```

which I obtained from db using jdbc connection in Spring

```
@GetMapping("/dashboard")
public String Data() {
    Connection conn = null;
    List<Map<String, Object>> listOfDates = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
        String countQuery = "SELECT migrations.mignum, migration_states.statemigrations.projectleader, migrations.productiondate, migrations.installationtiers, migrations.targetplatform, migrations.apprelated, migrations.appversion FROM migrations, migration_states WHERE migrations.productiondate='2018-07-07";
        QueryRunner queryRunner = new QueryRunner();
        listOfDates = queryRunner.query(conn, countQuery, new MapListHandler());
        conn.close();
    } catch (SQLException se) {
        se.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        DbUtils.closeQuietly(conn);
    }
    return new Gson().toJson(listOfDates);
}
```

I want to parse result and save it in another json as follows
 1. 1st result

```
[
{
"state":"Completed"
"value": [
    {"mignum":146289,"projectleader":"Eric Lok","productiondate":"Jun 6, 2018","installationtiers":"Windows Server","targetplatform":"Production","apprelated":"UPS Pickup Point Web Application","appversion":"2.25"};
    {"mignum":146381,"projectleader":"James Rice","productiondate":"Jun 6, 2018","installationtiers":"Linux Web WL10","targetplatform":"Production","apprelated":"Content Only","appversion":""},
    {"mignum":146381,"projectleader":"James Rice","productiondate":"Jun 6, 2018","installationtiers":"Linux Web WL10","targetplatform":"Production","apprelated":"Content Only","appversion":""}
]
}
{
"state":"Pending Migration to Production"
"value": [
    {"mignum":146461,"projectleader":"Nishith Jani","productiondate":"Jun 6, 2018","installationtiers":"Linux BEA WL12","targetplatform":"Production","apprelated":"Tracking Comp","appversion":"1801.20"}.
    {"mignum":146574,"projectleader":"Nishith Jani","productiondate":"Jun 6, 2018","installationtiers":"Linux BEA WL12","targetplatform":"Production","apprelated":"Trackin Comp","appversion":"01-00-07-17"}
]
}
{
"state":"Pending Approval by Development in Windward"
"value": [
    {"mignum":146461,"projectleader":"Nishith Jani","productiondate":"Jun 6, 2018","installationtiers":"Linux BEA WL12","targetplatform":"Production","apprelated":"Tracking Comp","appversion":"1801.20"}.
    {"mignum":146574,"projectleader":"Nishith Jani","productiondate":"Jun 6, 2018","installationtiers":"Linux BEA WL12","targetplatform":"Production","apprelated":"Trackin Comp","appversion":"01-00-07-17"}
]
}
]
```

2. 2nd result

```
[
  { "state":"Completed", "count": "2"},
  { "state":"Pending Migration to Production", "count": "2"},
  { "state":"Pending Approval by Development in Windward", "count": "2"}
]
```

I'm new to this json manipulation in Java/Spring side, so any one help me,because I'm stuck at this point from long time

Comment: You can use DTO projection. e.g StateDTO with properties state and map of value.

Comment: What is the relation between `migrations` and `migration_states`?

Comment: migration_states is coming from migrations table from DB

Comment: You should stop thinking in terms of JSON manipulation, and in terms of Map<String, Object>. Instead, create a class representing what you read from the database. Create another class representing the structure of the JSON you want to generate, and mapped to JSON using Jackson annotations. Then read the data from the DB, creating instances of the first class; transform these objects into instances of the second class, and ask Jackson to write these instances of the second class as JSON.

Comment: @JB Nizet 
I understood the overall what you are saying, but not confident. Can you add some similar code to understand what you are saying ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using plain JDBC, it might be more interesting to use JPA (+ Spring Data) since this allows you to work with classes/objects rather than maps, for example:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "migrations")
public class Migration {
    @Id
    private Long mignum;
    private LocalDate productiondate;
    private String installationtiers;
    private String targetplatform;
    private String apprelated;
    private String appversion;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "mignum")
    private MigrationState state;

    // Getters + Setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "migration_states")
public class MigrationState {
    @Id
    private Long mignum;
    private String state;
    private String projectleader;

    // Getters + Setters
}
```

To make a query, you can create a repository and use JPQL:

```java
public interface MigrationRepository extends JpaRepository<Migration, Long> {
    List<Migration> findByProductiondate(LocalDate productiondate);
}
```

These classes (`Migration` and `MigrationState`) represent your database model. Since your question didn't contain all the database related information (only the query you wrote), this could be slightly different in your case.

> **Note**: You don't really need JPA, most of this answer can be used without JPA as well, but you'll have to do the mapping between the `Map<String, Object>` and `Migration` by yourself.

However, next to those classes, you also need classes that represent the output you prefer. For example, this would work for your second output:

```java
public class SimpleStateSummaryDTO {
    private String state;
    private int count;
}
```

And this would work for your first output:

```java
public class StateSummaryDTO {
    private String state;
    private List<MigrationDTO> value;

    // Getters + Setters
}
```

Rather than using the `Migration` class that represents your database, you should create a new class to represent the migration in your JSON, which we could call `MigrationDTO`:

```java
public class MigrationDTO {
    private Long mignum;
    private String projectleader;
    private LocalDate productiondate;
    private String installationtiers;
    private String targetplatform;
    private String apprelated;
    private String appversion;

    // Getters + Setters
}
```

> **Note**: A DTO stands for **D**ata **T**ransfer **O**bject, and represents the data that is used for communication between two processes, in your case your API and your consumer.

Now that you have these classes, you can use the Java 8 functional API to group the `Migration` classes by their state, for example:

```java
repository
    .findByProductiondate(LocalDate.of(2018, 6, 6)).stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(migration -> migration.getState().getState()))
```

However, this would return a `Map<String, List<Migration>>`, which isn't what you want. Now you could either write your own collector, or stream this map again so that you can map it to what you need.

For example, for the second output that would become:

```java
repository
    .findByProductiondate(LocalDate.of(2018, 6, 6)).stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(migration -> migration.getState().getState()))
    .entrySet().stream()
    .map(entry -> new SimpleStateSummaryDTO(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().size()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

What we do here is that for each `Map.Entry<String, List<Migration>>`,  we're creating a new `SimpleStateSummaryDTO` containing the state and the size of the list.

The first output on the other hand requires an additional mapping of `Migration` to `MigrationDTO`:

```java
repository
    .findByProductiondate(LocalDate.of(2018, 6, 6)).stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(migration -> migration.getState().getState()))
    .entrySet().stream()
    .map(entry -> new StateSummaryDTO(
        entry.getKey(),
        entry.getValue().stream()
            .map(migration -> new MigrationDTO(
                migration.getMignum(),
                migration.getState().getProjectleader(),
                migration.getProductiondate(),
                migration.getInstallationtiers(),
                migration.getTargetplatform(),
                migration.getApprelated(),
                migration.getAppversion()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList())))
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

> **Note**: You don't need the Java 8 functional API and you could write some traditional logic using loops. This just makes it a little easier.

Now that you have your desired output as objects, you're pretty much done, since Spring will automatically convert objects to JSON using Jackson, for example:

```java
@GetMapping
public List<SimpleStateSummaryDTO> findSimple() {
    return repository
        .findByProductiondate(LocalDate.of(2018, 6, 6)).stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(migration -> migration.getState().getState()))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .map(entry -> new SimpleStateSummaryDTO(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().size()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: Thank You very much. This is what I was looking for. Your solution actually helped me.